# using grep -n (data) file1.txt > file2.txt

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I'm trying to understand a shell code which includes a line like this:

```
grep -n data  file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Where **data** is the text i want to search for.

What does this command mean?

Comment: `man grep`? The `>` redirects the output of the `grep` command to `file2.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a detailled answer here: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=%20grep%20-n%20data%20file1.txt%20%3E%20file2.txt

To sum it up:

- `grep` will look for the string `data` in `file1.txt` and will output both the matching lines and their line number (because of the `-n` flag).
  You could read the manual (`man grep`) to have a better understanding of what `grep` does.
- The output will be redirected into `file2.txt`; that's what `>` is used for